# How can I find child gameobject?

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject

I want to say somethings like..

```
Gameobject.find(child gameobject of specific parent Gameobject)
```

Can anyone help me.
thanks!

Comment: Look at this http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10417/how-can-i-access-the-children-of-a-transform.html

Comment: [There is even a find function on the transform](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`GameObject.Find` will search for a gameobject in the scene. To search a gameobject from a parent, use `Transform`.

There are 2 ways of doing it:

1. `transform.Find("childname")`
2. `transform.FindChild("childname")`

The 2nd option is deprecated but still functional, so you'd better use the 1st option.

Comment: when i am trying this code.i found one error like..."Cannot convert type `UnityEngine.Transform' to `UnityEngine.GameObject"

Comment: it is because `Transform.find("childname")` returns a type of Transform. If you want to get the gameobject, just add .gameObject at the end: `Transform.find("childname").gameObject`

Comment: I made user3164248's changes to this answer (just to avoid confusion).

Answer (score 7):

If a GameObject are you looking for in hierarchy it must be like:

```
transform.Find("head/eyes")
transform.FindChild("head/eyes")
```

Comment: Thank you! The "Find()" call was returning NULL for me and I saw in the Unity docs that it doesn't traverse the hierarchy (to get sub-children) by default. Using the forward slash allows you to do that (e.g. "ParentName/ChildName/GrandchildName" to get "GrandchildName").

Answer (score 5):

Fixing Jay Kazama's answer. The correct answers are:

1. transform.Find ("childname")
2. transform.FindChild ("childname")

With small t (property transform, not class Transform).

Comment: I changed Kazama's answer to include these fixes.

Answer (score 5):

For answers above stating `transform.FindChild("childname")` as Answer, this is to inform you that `transform.FindChild("childname")` is deprecated.

Use this, this will work as expected

```
transform.Find("childName");
```

if you want to find Child of a GameObject by name, use this,

```
GameObject head = HeadPanel;    // just for reference
head.transorm.Find("childName").gameObject;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by 
 GetChild(index of child members)

Comment: The bad thing about using the GetChild (index) is that if you change the order of the objects you lose the reference to them