# Getting child object of gameObject in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject, subobject

I have Object "Unit" with sub Objects "Monster and Health.
I also have Object Tower that has sphere collider.
Also I have OnTriggerEnter(Collider co) function in Tower Object that detects Unit.

When it does I can for example print the name "Unit" by accessing it
co.gameObject.name, or even co.name, which I guess is the same.

But how can I get the first subobject of unit for example. I mean Monster object, but not by name but just the FIRST SUB OBJECT of Unit object ?

***UPDATE***

Using this code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider co)
{
    Debug.Log(co.gameObject.transform.GetChild(0));
}
```

Causes an exception:

```
UnityException: Transform child out of bounds
Tower.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider co) (at Assets/Scripts/Tower.cs:19)
```

**UPDATE 2**
print(co.transform.childCount); gives 2

And that's correct cause I have

```
Unit
>

Monster

HealthBar
```

subobjects

**Update 3**
Tower code.
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;

```
public class Tower : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The Bullet
    public GameObject Bullet;

    // Rotation Speed
    public float rotationSpeed = 35;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed, Space.World);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider co)
    {

        print(co.transform.childCount);

        if (co.gameObject.name == "Unit(Clone)")
        { 

            GameObject g = (GameObject)Instantiate(Bullet, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            g.GetComponent<Bullet>().target = co.transform;
        }
    }
}
```

This Code Somehow manages to print twice

```
2
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
Tower:OnTriggerEnter(Collider) (at Assets/Scripts/Tower.cs:20)
0
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:print(Object)
Tower:OnTriggerEnter(Collider) (at Assets/Scripts/Tower.cs:20)
```

Comment: Out of bounds means that there are no children in the transform. You'll have to check that first. See http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-childCount.html

Comment: I've checked and I receive 2 which means that I trully have 2 subobjects. What can I do now ?

Comment: Are you sure that you are working with correct gameobject? co in OnTriggerEnter(Collider co) is the entering entity. Show us all of your code.

Comment: Actually when I ran simulation once more, I see in debug 2 messages. First 2, and then at the same time 0. How come ?

Comment: The Above code somehow prints twice in debug. first "2" then "0". And I have only one print!!! :(

Comment: I believe that debugging your solution is beyond the scope of this question. The problem may be in that you have attached this 'Tower' script to the item that collides with another tower. You'll have to check your Unity project for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find child gameobject?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763587/how-can-i-find-child-gameobject)

Comment: Try not to answer or comment on questions that are million-times duplicates.  One of thousands of informative QA on this topic .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27389984/294884  The clutter on this tag is huge and has to be reduced guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to operate on GameObject's `transform`. You can use `Transform.GetChild(int index)` function.

You will probably first have to check if there are any children because GetChild throws exceptions if you get out of bounds of the array. For that you'll have to use `Transform.childCount`.

More info can be found here:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-childCount.html

Comment: It worked. problem was with bullet object which secondly called print. Great thanks for the Help!